# Communication between android native and react native

Tags: android, android-layout, localization, react-native

I know in IOS I can communicate between native and react native, for example I could pass an object-c property to react native.. How could I do the same with android?

Actually I want to build application for android with react native and this should be bilingual app (english/arabic), the default language will be Arabic, and when the user press on English icon at the "ToolbarAndroid" the language of the interface and the layout direction should be changed, so I need to call a function (from js file) at native that changes the language and direction depending on the passed variable.

Is that possible??

Comment: https://medium.com/@john1jan/communicating-to-and-from-native-ui-components-in-react-native-android-b8abcfb2f9c8#.rlxuhsdwg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's two ways you can go about doing this:

1) If your main purpose is just to get translations, you can use a React-Native NPM package that handles localization through your javascript code, like this [ReactNativeLocalization plugin](https://github.com/stefalda/ReactNativeLocalization).

2) If you require native Android code, you can create your own Native Module. React-Native has a guide on how to do it here. [React-Native: Native Module Guide](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html#content).

From experience, its easier and faster to use the plugin as you won't actually need to touch native code or make an additional module. This way, if you ever plan to port to iOS, you'll also have everything set and ready to go in terms of translations.

Comment: Thank you, actually in-addition to translation, I need also to make the layout direction RTL in case the user select Arabic language and LTR otherwise.. I think in this case I have to work with native Android code

Comment: You can still do this with React-Native. All you need to do is save the state as to which direction it should be based on language and then choose the appropriate stylesheet for it.

Comment: @Zidail is there a way if want some java code and corresponding layout, any idea?

Comment: @ManjeetSingh Something like this? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-components-android.html

Comment: @Zidail concerning the 2nd option about communication with the native module, is that native module a class within the android folder of the same react-native project?